# How can I identity query that use most DTU?

Tags: sql-server, azure, optimization, resources

I'm not sure which are the most resource consumer on a DB I have on Azure (which is a Premium P2: 250 DTUs):

[image]

The most, using this query:

```
SELECT  
    AVG(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Average CPU Utilization In Percent', 
    MAX(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Maximum CPU Utilization In Percent', 
    AVG(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Average Data IO In Percent', 
    MAX(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Maximum Data IO In Percent', 
    AVG(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Average Log Write Utilization In Percent', 
    MAX(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Maximum Log Write Utilization In Percent', 
    AVG(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Average Memory Usage In Percent', 
    MAX(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Maximum Memory Usage In Percent' 
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats;
```

[image]

But if I watch at the query Performance overwiew, I don't see these problems:

[image]

So, what can I do to understand where the real problem is? These DTU for this machine is so higher.

Comment: AFAIK The CPU capacity could have only been maxed out for 1 millisecond in that time interval but that is still going to mean that the max CPU reached in that time interval was 100%. Whereas the other stats you are looking at will be aggregated over a longer time period. Unless you are seeing queries with long duration as they can't get onto the CPU there probably isn't any actual problem here. You could potentially look at your max dop settings to prevent a parallel query using all cores though.

Comment: @MartinSmith the DTU are very high, that's the actual problem here. Some peaks at 100% scare me...

Comment: DTU of 100% just means that at least one component of it reached 100% - in this case the CPU component

Comment: DTU isn't like Cosmos RU - you aren't going to start getting throttled just purely on the basis that it is showing up as 100% - it just means that for at least one moment you were using all of the available capacity for at least one element